# Remove the word if a character repeats multiple times

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I want to remove a word from the sentence if the word starts with 4 or more repeating characters.

```
eg: 
['aaaaaaa is really good', 'nott something great',
       'ssssssssssssstackoverflow is a great community']
```

I need an output something like this:
eg:

`['is really good', 'nott something great', 'is a great community']`

I tried something like this:

```
^(\S)\1{3,}
```

It does remove those repeating characters but not the word. Thanks

Comment: Just add `\S*\s` to the end?

Comment: Show how you tried to apply the regex

Comment: @MadPhysicist I first tried `re.sub('^(\S)\1{3,}\S*\s', '', sentence)` and it didn't work but later tried to used string literal `r` `re.sub(r'^(\S)\1{3,}\S*\s', '', sentence)` and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `\S*\s` to the end of the pattern:

```
words = ['aaaaaaa is really good', 'nott something great','ssssssssssssstackoverflow is a great community']
newWords = [re.sub(r'^(\S)\1{3,}\S*\s', '', word) for word in words]
```

Output:

```
['is really good', 'nott something great', 'is a great community']
```

If the string may be composed of only one word, then make the final space optional, `\s?` instead of `\s`.

Comment: Is there a way to edit the regex to look for such word not just at the beginning but anywhere in the sentence?

Comment: @user214 Remove the `^` at the beginning.

Comment: Also replace it with `\b` to ensure you're at the start at the word

Comment: @CertainPerformance `re.sub(r"(\S)\1{3,}\S*\s", " " , "wwwwwaaa wwwwww is aadadasdaaaaaaa good")` I tried to remove `^` but it didn't gave the required output that is `is good` because every other word in that sentence have a repeating character 4 or more times

Comment: @user214 Your repeating condition `(\S)\1{3,}` means that the starting character must be repeated 4+ times, but `aadadas` repeats `a` only 2 times

Comment: @CertainPerformance But in `aadadasdaaaaaaa` the `a's` at the end repeat 4 or more times. I want to be able to delete these kind of words as well. Is there any modification I could make to my regex so such words will also be removed

Comment: @user214 Your question asks `I want to remove a word from the sentence if the word **starts with** 4 or more repeating characters.` Add `\S*` to the beginning of the pattern to allow the repeating characters to be anywhere.

Comment: At first my query was regarding it later I just wanted to know if there's a way to match such words any words and substitute them. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: @CertainPerformance `re.sub(r"\S*(\S)\1{3,}\S*\s", "" , "aaaaaa")` I added `\S*` but it is failing if the sentence has one word.

Comment: @user214 See the final line in the answer: `If the string may be composed of only one word, then make the final space optional, \s? instead of \s.`